# Where to find a handwritten font with English and Chinese?

Tags: fonts

I am preparing a book which needs some material to appear like it is hand-written. I see many fonts available which simulate this look, however, I need something which also has hand-written fonts for both English letters and simplified Chinese characters, preferably with an open source or similar license. Where can I find such a font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ps123.net/photoshop/special/shouxieti/index.html) are some choices of Chinese hand-writing font:

Actually, you can search `手写字体` using search engine, like [baidu](http://baidu.com)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible, you're unlikely to find a font you really like that has both English (Latin characters) and Chinese.  Most font designers will design for one or the other and even if a font contains both, it may have poor quality Latin but good Chinese or vice-versa.

More realistic would be to find two separate fonts - a Latin one you like and a Chinese one you like - and switch fonts according to the current language (possibly even making use of font fall-back in whatever application you're using).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is considered advertising and all, but I get all my fonts from dafont.com. You can even browse on category/style. If I'm not mistaken, the free-downloadable fonts there are all freeware.